# Advice needed for equipment and How-To material for taking pictures of items for ecommerce site?

Tags: lighting, product-photography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What equipment is needed for a basic product shoot studio?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/what-equipment-is-needed-for-a-basic-product-shoot-studio)

I have a DSLR camera and I consider myself a newbie photographer. I want to take photos of items like pottery, shoes and other stuff in similar sizes where the items look clear & crisp in terms of lighting. It's for a personal ecommerce site.

I came across once some equipment made for hobbyists for doing such photography. I think it was a cube with one side open, made of white cloth?, and an umbrella and some lights. It was a setup which costed less than $100 or $200. I wish I bookmarked that page.

I don't know what such equipment is called and therefore I don't know how to do a specific search.

Any recommendations on what inexpensive equipment to get and any kind of tutorials (web, video, book, ebook) on how to do this kind of object shooting like the professionals do?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/what-equipment-is-needed-for-a-basic-product-shoot-studio plus http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4631/what-are-the-best-resources-for-indoor-product-photography

Answer (score 1):

You'll find tons of different kinds of setups if you look for "product photography" setups.
Strobist has a DIY setup for about $10 :) : http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/07/how-to-diy-10-macro-photo-studio.html

You don't need to use the exact setup, just one that kind of gives the same effect.